# MVC5 Partial View with Ajax.Beginform ClientSide Validation not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have spent the last 3 days reading and searching for a resolution to this problem and have not found one.  So im reaching out for somehelp.

Ive got a pretty complex View that has multiple partial views but the concept is simple.  I click on a link to "create" and it opens a bootstrap Modal which is populated by a partial view.  In this partial view I am using ajax.beginForm to post.  However, the client side validation is not working.  Also, when the server responds with the modelstate.isvalid as false the validation summary doesn not show either.   Here is the code...

This is my partial view that is loaded in the modal

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateBox",
                                new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                    HttpMethod = "post",
                                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                    UpdateTargetId = "myCellarLocations",
                                    OnBegin="ValidateForm",
                                    OnSuccess = "CloseBoxModal"
                                }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create Box</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.CellarLocationId)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayValue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
```

}

Here is my controller code

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("Cellar/CreateBox/{Id?}")]
    public ActionResult CreateBox(int id)
    {
        CreateBoxViewModel model = new CreateBoxViewModel();
        model.CellarLocationId = id;

        return PartialView("_CreateBox", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Cellar/CreateBox/{Id?}")]
    public ActionResult CreateBox(CreateBoxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            //Create Box
            Box box = new Box();
            box.CellarLocationId = viewModel.CellarLocationId;
            box.DisplayValue = viewModel.DisplayValue;
            vd.CreateBox(box);

            //Get Cellar Locations
            List<CellarLocation> model = vd.GetCellarLocationsByUserId(userId).ToList();
            return PartialView("_CellarLocations", model);
        }

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return PartialView("_CreateBox", viewModel);

    }
```

Here is the scripts on main view

```
function CloseBoxModal(data) {
        alert("close");
        $("form").removeData("validator");
        $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
        $('#Box').modal('hide');
    }



    function ValidateForm() {
        alert("here");
        return $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
    }
```

My webconfig already has

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

and I have the following in my bundles included

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/cbt").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/scripts/custom-validators.js"));
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. There has got to be an easier and cleaner way to do client side validation on a partial view form and to show the validation errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer.  You need to remove data and call the parse on the validator after the content is loaded into the modal.

```
function CreateBox(id) {
        var url = "/Cellar/CreateBox"; // the url to the controller
        $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
            $('#box-modal-content').html(data);
            $('#Box').modal('show');
            $('#createBoxForm').removeData("validator");
            $('#createBoxForm').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#createBoxForm');

        });
    }
```